# VoiceOver won't read information from aria-* attribute for <div> or <p>

Tags: iphone, accessibility, wai-aria, voiceover, wcag2.0

I want some mobile page to be read via VoiceOver(Safari) and TalkBack(Chrome) in browser.

**html code:**

```
            <span id="label_span">some description</span>
            <p aria-labelledby="label_span">
                <span>main text</span>
            </p>
```

Instead of reading '***main text***' I need screen reader to read '***some description***'.

TalkBack works correctly for me, but VoiceOver(in mobile Safari browser) read '*main text*' (even aria-label, aria-describedby doesn't work for me)

How to make VoiceOver system read content of aria-* linked element instead of particular element.

Answer (score 3):

`aria-labelledby` works with elements that have explicit roles (or implicit roles) and/or are interactive elements. In short, `aria-labelledby` will not work with either a `<div>` nor a `<span>`.

Something like a header (`<h#>`) would be an example where you can use `aria-labelledby` to connect its text value to something like a `<section>`.

Barring an example, I cannot offer much more than that.